# For performance, does it make any performance difference to have a String temporarily in a loop or call it directly?

Tags: java, algorithm

```
ArrayList<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>(){{
    add("a");
    add("b");
    add("c");
    add("d");
}};
int size = strings.size();
```

This is the part that I want to know which one to use and why.

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    String temp_string = strings.get(i);
    someMethod(temp_string);
}
```

or

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
       someMethod(strings.get(i));
}
```

Does it make any performance difference? Does the `temp_string` points to the String saved in the arraylist part of memory or does it allocate another space in memory in each loop to save the `temp_string`?

Comment: Why don't you profile the code and compare the results?

Comment: Actually I did, but I still can't see much difference, but since I'm gonna work with a lot of data in the future, I would like to already make it better

Comment: @JonK it is not *that* simple.

Comment: If you can't see much difference then increase the number of iterations. If you're running the code 10,000 times, try running it 1,000,000 times instead. If there's still not much difference then you're probably in the realms of premature optimisation.

Comment: There's not going to be a difference.  Stop worrying.

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if it made any difference, not only because creating a temporary reference on the stack and then copying it to the function call parameter costs very little, but mostly because no serious compiler would miss the obvious optimization.

Still, you cannot be sure without testing.

Answer (score 1):

It may help to walk through what is going on in both cases to see what kind of difference you should expect:

- In the case with a temporary variable, you obtain an object reference, store it in a temporary variable, pass it on to `someMethod`, and then let the temporary variable go out of scope
- In the case without a temporary variable, you obtain ab object reference, and pass it on to `someMethod` directly.

From this you should conclude right away that if there is any difference, the advantage would be on the side of the implementation that does fewer things, i.e. the implementation without a temporary variable.

There are situations when making a temporary variable would help you improve performance. Here is one example, based on your code snippet:

```
for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
    String temp_string = strings.get(i);
    for (int j = 0 ; j != 10000 ; j++) {
        someMethod(temp_string, 2*j+1);
    }
}
```

This snippet reuses the results of `strings.get(i)` ten thousand times, so when `someMethod` is really fast, you might see a little difference. This is not a guaranteed win, however: you need to profile to see if the change makes a difference or not.

Another change that may make a difference with fast `someMethod` implementations and long `strings` lists is a `foreach` loop:

```
for(String s : strings){
    someMethod(s);
}
```

This is applicable when you do not need to use the index inside the loop. The code may be a little faster, because internally it avoids an index check in the array list.

Answer (score 0):

First off, I believe in the second algorithm you meant strings.get(i) not temp_string.get(i) because temp_string isn't declared.

Now to the point, the first algorithm takes a couple of clock cycles longer. Notice you have all the same calls PLUS an assignment operation. This will be negligible in most situations but in a high performance environment it could be costly.

Comment: The compiler could optimize out the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

The scope of `temp_string` is identical in both cases, that is, limited to the for loop. The generated byte code is almost identical.

```
  public void foo1(List<String> list) {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
      String str = list.get(i);
      someMethod(str);
    }
  }

  public void foo2(List<String> list) {
    for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
      someMethod(list.get(i));
    }
  }


public void foo1(java.util.List);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_2
   3:   aload_1
   4:   invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.size:()I
   9:   if_icmpge   34
   12:  aload_1
   13:  iload_2
   14:  invokeinterface #3,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   19:  checkcast   #4; //class java/lang/String
   22:  astore_3
   23:  aload_0
   24:  aload_3
   25:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method someMethod:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   28:  iinc    2, 1
   31:  goto    2
   34:  return

public void foo2(java.util.List);
  Code:
   0:   iconst_0
   1:   istore_2
   2:   iload_2
   3:   aload_1
   4:   invokeinterface #2,  1; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.size:()I
   9:   if_icmpge   32
   12:  aload_0
   13:  aload_1
   14:  iload_2
   15:  invokeinterface #3,  2; //InterfaceMethod java/util/List.get:(I)Ljava/lang/Object;
   20:  checkcast   #4; //class java/lang/String
   23:  invokevirtual   #5; //Method someMethod:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
   26:  iinc    2, 1
   29:  goto    2
   32:  return
```

The only difference with the first loop (assigning to a String, then passing the String to the method) is an extra `astore_3` and `aload_3`. This should be easy for the JVM to optimize out.

Also note that the second loop (no extra variable assignment) is easier to read.